# What can a malicious person do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Well I'm kind of fascinated by the safety of my projects and I have an issue that does not leave my head.

I have a page to recover password, and the user needs to fill out the form with a valid data, in addition to performing the recaptcha test.

To facilitate the user experience, I do the checks via ajax, if I do not return any errors, I free the page.

```
$.ajax(configAjax).done(data => {

       if(data.result !== "success") {
           sendErrorMessage(data.message);
           grecaptcha.reset();
           event.preventDefault();
       }
       else {
           done = true;
       }

       toggleLoading();

})
```

Okay, all normal .. But I've always heard that it is not to rely on any data on the client side.

If they were able to change, for example, the signal from !== to ===, the user would be able to perform the search without performing the recaptcha.

I thought of doing the recaptcha check twice, one in ajax, and one when the page was updated with the POST request, but the API returns an error because two requests were made in a short interval.

My question is, is it possible for someone to do this?

Comment: it would be nice if you translated this to english so more people could help you.

Comment: I translated, sorry.

Comment: You cannot trust any data from the client.  The client can skip your JS altogether and send any kind of request.

Comment: Anything you do on the client is just for user convenience. The server has to do its own validation, and should not send any data to the client if this fails.

Comment: Okay, I will remove the recaptcha check via ajax. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application is implemented correctly, this should not allow the user to bypass the CAPTCHA check.

The AJAX request validates the CAPTCHA response on the server. If it succeeds, the server should arrange for future API calls to be validated. It might return a token that has to be included in future API calls, set a cookie, or it could set a server-side session variable. When the application makes additional calls to the API, the server should check this data; if it's not valid, the calls are rejected.

If you change `!==` to `===`, the user won't get an error message. But they still won't be able to use the application, because the above authentication information won't have been set up. The server still knows that you didn't give a correct CAPTCHA response.

The upshot is that you can never do authentication entirely on the client. You can do client-side validation to improve the user experience, but it has to be duplicated on the server. And the server has to do it on every request; you can't assume that the client will follow the normal path through the pages of the application. For instance, even if you only link to `application.php` from `login.php`, `application.php` can't assume that the user has actually gone through the login checks -- there's nothing stopping someone from putting the `application.php` URL in the browser's address bar. `login.php` has to do something that the client can't spoof, and `application.php` has to verify that this has been done in the current session.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will take it as apprenticeship. In this case, I will do the recaptcha verification only when the page is refreshed.

Via client-side, I'll just check if the 'g-recaptcha-response' value is not undefined